# Heroku with Let's Encrypt: Couldn't find that sni endpoint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku, lets-encrypt, certbot

I made an SSL certificate for subdomain.mysite.com using [Let's Encrypt](http://letsencrypt.org).

I did that using the `certbot` command.

```
brew install certbot
sudo certbot certonly --manual
```

I got the following response:

> IMPORTANT NOTES:
>
> - Congratulations!
>   Your certificate and chain have been saved at:
>   `/etc/letsencrypt/live/subdomain.mysite.com/fullchain.pem`
>   Your key file has been saved at:
>   `/etc/letsencrypt/live/subdomain.mysite.com/privkey.pem`
>   Your certificate will expire on **2021-07-23**. To obtain a new or    tweaked
>   version of this certificate in the future, simply run    certbot
>   again. To non-interactively renew *all* of your    certificates, run
>   `certbot renew`

Now I want to add this to heroku by running:

```
heroku certs:add /etc/letsencrypt/live/subdomain.mysite.com/fullchain.pem /etc/letsencrypt/live/subdomain.mysite.com/privkey.pem --type endpoint
```

> === Almost done! Which of these domains on this application would you like this certificate associated with?
> ? Select domains subdomain.mysite.com
> ▸    Couldn't find that sni endpoint.

I can now see the certificate by running the following command:

```
heroku certs
```

```
Name             Endpoint                                  Common Name(s)        Expires               Trusted  Type      Domains
───────────────  ────────────────────────────────────────  ────────────────────  ────────────────────  ───────  ────────  ───────
okugama-59392    depp-basions-garble.ssl.herokudns.com     subdomain.mysite.com  2021-07-23 11:45 UTC  True     Endpoint  2
```

And when I run the `heroku domains` command I will see the domain but with the SNI = `undefined`.

```
=== artists-way Custom Domains
Domain Name          DNS Record Type DNS Target                                                SNI Endpoint 
subdomain.mysite.com CNAME           mammalias-makderel-ydfdsesesfssfsedwsdkn6wd.herokudns.com undefined
```

Accessing the subdomain in a browser it will tell me that a secure connection can't be established.

So, how may I configure a SNI Endpoint or what do I need to do in order for this to work.

Comment: Why do this yourself? [Heroku's ACM](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/automated-certificate-management) uses Let's Encrypt under the hood and is trivial to set up.

Comment: @Chris: I should mention that I'm using free dynos for this app. Also there is a tutorial that describes how to do it using CloudFlare, which I don't use: https://dev.to/densityx/setting-up-a-custom-domain-name-and-free-ssl-certificate-for-heroku-apps-2063